# Rails: working with double plurals (has_and_belongs_to_many)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many

What's the best way to work with double plurals in Rails? I've got a few `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationships, and I want something like:

```
@templates = current_user.brands.templates
```

But the closest I can do is something like this:

```
current_user.brands.each do |b|
  @templates = b.templates
end
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Should really switch to `has_many :through`.

Comment: Yeah, starting to see that. Didn't realise that restriction on `has_and_belongs_to_many`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use through association in user model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :templates, :through => : brands
  ....
end
```

Then,

```
@templates = current_user.templates
```

Or,

You can also get result by iterating over brands array and collecting templates for each brand:

```
@templates = current_user.brands.map{|brand| brand.templates}.flatten
```

Comment: That's good but it ignores duplicates (i.e., if two `brands` have access to the same template).

Comment: @emm: but why do you want duplicate records to appear twice having same id.

Comment: It's about access: a user can have many brands, and brands can have many templates (some are the same). So users should be able to access all the templates their brands can without any duplication.

Comment: are using has_and_belongs_to_many relationship between User and Brand.

Comment: I am, yeah, but I don't have to.

Comment: through association will always find distinct records. The converted query for current_user.templates will be "SELECT DISTINCT `templates`.* FROM `templates` INNER JOIN `brands` ON `templates`.`id` = `brands`.`template_id` WHERE `brands`.`user_id` = 1". So if u want duplicate records also, use current_user.brands.map{|brand| brand.templates}.flatten

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can have something like `brands.templates`. If you'd like to have a collection of templates from multiple brands, the only way to do so is to "collect" the templates from each brand you're looking through:

```
@templates = []
current_user.brands.each do |b|
  @templates.push(b.templates)
end
```

A `has_and_belongs_to_many` association, like a `has_many` association, generates the methods `brand.templates` and `template.brands`, but not `brands.templates`.